# JSON Output to Python Dictionary - Difficulty understanding

Tags: python, json, dictionary

New to JSON and Python. I successfully call and can get an output using something like this

```
def lendbook(currency='xtl'): #GET /lendbook/:currency

    r = requests.get(URL + "/lendbook/" + currency, verify=False)
    rep = r.json()

    return rep

print lendbook()
```

The data prints out fine but a real muddle for a new beginner. A sample is below from the Python console

```
{u'bids': [{u'timestamp': u'1405112154.0', u'rate': u'0.365', u'frr': u'No', u'amount': u'20.0', u'period': 30}], u'asks': [{u'timestamp': u'1405143214.0', u'rate': u'1.9345', u'frr': u'No', u'amount': u'0.72115369', u'period': 2}, {u'timestamp': u'1401975696.0', u'rate': u'2.0', u'frr': u'Yes', u'amount': u'0.53', u'period': 30}, {u'timestamp': u'1405011490.0', u'rate': u'2.0', u'frr': u'Yes', u'amount': u'3.44796922', u'period': 30}, {u'timestamp': u'1405137594.0', u'rate': u'2.0', u'frr': u'Yes', u'amount': u'0.12279759', u'period': 2}, {u'timestamp': u'1405139396.0', u'rate': u'2.0', u'frr': u'Yes', u'amount': u'1.84883351', u'period': 2}, {u'timestamp': u'1405140302.0', u'rate': u'2.0', u'frr': u'Yes',
```

Obviously I want to format the date and in fact really only after the rate and period. What looping structure for dictionaries should I use as when I use a FOR loop I only seem to return the words 'bids' and 'asks'. There is obviously another structure in the dictionary I am not understanding?

Really appreciate help as I get my head around JSON and Python dictionaries

Comment: Iterating over a dictionary iterates over its keys. Use `for key, value in d.iteritems()` instead.

Comment: I think what you're missing is that the dictionary contains a list of dictionaries; it's all nested. You might understand it better if you pretty-print the JSON or the dict.

Comment: I find that `pprint` is an amazing debuging tool
`from pprint import ppriny; pprint(lendbook())`. You may also not nee to do a loop if you know the path to the data you want in the response: `print(lendbook()['bids'][0]['timestamp'])`, or only iterate over the `list`s with a `for` and not iterate over the dictionary items themselves.

Comment: hmmm need to research pretty-print. I have not come across it

Comment: My gosh pprint has changed my life! Very nice debugging tool.

Comment: ThorSummoner +1 I think you solved some parts of this concisely for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the JSON object you are getting in return contains objects(lists) (i.e, "bids", and "asks") So I guess you are confused as to why you aren't accessing the values.
I suggest you first get a hold of the object you are interested in (say "bids");

```
bidsList = rep['bids']
```

As you can see that "bids" is a list of objects([] >> indicates). You can now iterate.

```
#[{'timestamp': '1405112154.0', 'rate': '0.365', 'frr': 'No', 'amount': '20.0', 'period': 30}]
>>> bidsList = rep['bids']
>>> for obj in bidsList:
>>>   print obj
... 
{'timestamp': '1405112154.0', 'rate': '0.365', 'frr': 'No', 'amount': '20.0', 'period': 30}
```

You can get the values like,

```
>>> for obj in bidsList:
>>>   print obj['timestamp']
....
1405112154.0 
>>>
```

I suggest you create classes named Bids, Asks and any other object type you know is returned in that JSON object of yours. You can then access the object (rep['theObject']) and create instance of Bids(pass the json object to it and get an instance) It will save you from all this as the logic of getting the object would go in the class itself. Better design I would say.

Also(let's just say you want to stick to this approach), if you don't want to hardcode things, say you want to write a code that is independent of what is returned in the JSON. In that case you can Iterator over the Dict returned ('rep') in your case and for every object that you get in an iteration, you check the type, if it is a dict itself, then you do the same for it (iterator over the keys), or if it is a list, you iterate like I mentioned, otherwise access the values through the keys.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

When you loop through a dictionary, you only loop through its `keys` using basic `for` loop.

Change that to `for key, value in dict.iteritems():`.

```
>>> obj = {'bids': [1000, 2999], 'asks': [4, 5]}
>>> for key, value in obj.iteritems():
...     print key, value
... 
bids [1000, 2999]
asks [4, 5]
>>>
```

Comment: When I use this  a for loop 
for i in lendbook():
        print i  
it returns
<type 'dict'>
bids
asks

Using the key and values you suggest returns
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

Print the type of the data using type(). This way you can know the type of data in the json & process it step by step.

Comment: It is definitely a dictionary. But I suspect it may have an array as one of its vales but cant make heads or tails of it from the JSON data